# Getting different outputs for DateTimeZone.getDefault() using joda timezone library on different machines

Tags: java, linux, timezone, jodatime

Why I am getting different outputs when I am running DateTimeZone.getDefault() on different machines (all are Redhat 5.7 Machines). They all are using JRE 1.6.0_38

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;;
```

public class test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("TimeZone is : "+DateTimeZone.getDefault());

}
```

}

I know that the joda documentation is giving some info as

> Gets the default TimeZone for this host. The source of the default
>   TimeZone may vary with implementation.

I need some explanation on this . Please help me :)

Comment: Log into each machine and run `/usr/bin/date +%Z`
and check that they all return the same timezone.

Comment: I could not run this on my RedHat machines. root:/users/sboddireddy:\>
>> /usr/bin/date +%Z
bash: /usr/bin/date: No such file or directory

Comment: Try just running `date` and see if that is on your path.